# g++: crash when accessing ostringstream::str().c_str()

Tags: c++, ostringstream

The code below fails on gcc 9.4.0. Is this just a bug, or have I done something stupid?

`log` declares an `ostringstream` object, writes a filename and a line number to it, and attempts to do something with the object's underlying `str().c_str()`.

Valgrind shows this crashing at the pointer access. The output I get is:

```
foo.cc, line 100
cptr is at 0x55c45e8f00c0, and is
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdarg>
    
using std::cout;
using std::ostringstream;
    
void log(const char *fname, int lineno) {
   ostringstream outstr;
   outstr << fname << ", line " << lineno;
   cout << outstr.str() << '\n';  // prints Ok
    
   const char *cptr = outstr.str().c_str();
   cout << "cptr is at " << (void*) cptr << ", and is " << cptr; // crash
}
    
int main() {
   log("foo.cc", 100);
}
```

Comment: Where does _"crash"_ stop, when you're running that code in your debugger? What's the exact valgrind report?

Comment: I don't run it in a debugger. Valgrind reports a large number of failures related to an invalid read of the pointer. When I run other variants of the code which print out the cptr value, valgrind reports that the pointer has been deleted.

Comment: *Is this just a bug, or have I done something stupid?*  Yes, and yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::ostringstream::str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) returns a temporary string which will be destructed at the end of the line, this then means `cptr` is a dangling pointer.

Try:

```
std::string str = outstr.str();
const char *cptr = str.c_str();
cout << "cptr is at " << (void*) cptr << ", and is " << cptr;
```

Comment: Or, if you really do want a temporary, just move the log message to another function, eg: `void logPtr(const char *cptr) { cout << "cptr is at " << (void*) cptr << ", and is " << cptr; } void log(const char *fname, int lineno) { ... logPtr(outstr.str().c_str()); }`